# Why this PHP code dosen't work?

Tags: php, button

I want to display the button and echo something when the button is clicked. i tried a lot but nothing worked. Please help me

```
<?php
//creating a button
echo '<input type="button" name="next" class="next" value="Next" />';

//if button is clicked
   if (isset($_POST['next'])) {  
echo "You clicked the next button" ;
   }
 else {
echo "Button Not Clicked";
}
?>
```

Comment: Use input type="submit"

Comment: You need to submit a form. See http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `type="submit"` instead of `type="button"`.
Updated code are as below.

**Note:** Be sure that your button is within a `form` with `post` method. 
i.e. `<form method='post'></form>`.

```
<?php
//creating a button
echo '<input type="submit" name="next" class="next" value="Next" />';

//if button is clicked
   if (isset($_POST['next'])) {  
echo "You clicked the next button" ;
   }
 else {
echo "Button Not Clicked";
}
?>
```

Comment: That wouldn't really do anything unless you have a form to submit though...

Comment: Yes, I have added a note in my answer. I am expecting he is using button within a form with post method

Answer (score 0):

Your button must be inside `<form method='post'></form>` tags with a type of submit.
change your first line to this:

```
echo '<form method="post"><input type="submit" name="next" class="next" value="Next" /></form>';
```

Comment: This is creating a text input with value 'next' :(

Comment: No its not...i tried it and it works. please copy/past the code and let me know how it went